# Find closest object values inside object of objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's start with an example.

I have a list of fruits and it's nutritions stored in JS objects. Then I get a vegetable which is not in the list but has same types of values as the keys in the fruits object.

How can I get the closest fruit from the fruit object to the vegetable given vegetable if 1) the nutrition values (sugar,salt,...) has same *values* (sugar = salt) 2) the nutrition values (sugar,salt,...) have different *values* (sugar > salt, so basicly check only for sugar). I know that's not a good explanation, but let's check the example below.

```
let fruits = {
 apple:{
  sugar:12,
  salt:5
 },
banana:{
  sugar:13,
  salt:3
 },
}

let cucumber = {
 sugar:12,
 salt:3
}

let closestFruitToCucumber = closest(cucumber, fruits) 
// apple (if checking only sugar)
// banana (if both sugar and salt are valued the same)


function closest(vegetable,fruitList){
 // here is the part which I am looking for.
}
```

I can post the code, which I have tried. There were plenty of them but none of them worked at all.

Comment: How do you define closest for two values? This is not a... well... apples to apples comparison.

Comment: I guess that you want to calculate the absolute difference for every matching key in the objects, and then sum these differences for each comparison, finally selecting the comparison with the lowest sum (but that's just my hunch and not at all clear from the question details).

Comment: @jsejcksn Yup, that's it. In one case, in the other one I don't want to sum at all, just check for one certain value. *Sugar in this example*

Comment: @kurome Well, in that case, you'll need a way to specify which property you want to use for comparison.

Comment: @FZs Uhm, if they are valued the same, then summing them up and dividing by the total count should do that right?

Comment: @kurome I still don't quite get what you're saying, but probably no. The absolute difference sum proposed by @jsejcksn sounds promising, you can do that like `abs(sugar1 - sugar2) + abs(salt1 - salt2)`.

Comment: @FZs Uhm yeah, my bad there. This should do the job. But how can I implement it when its in nested objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310762/find-closest-object-values-inside-object-of-objects?noredirect=1#comment129468394_73310762):

> I guess that you want to calculate the absolute difference for every matching key in the objects, and then sum these differences for each comparison, finally selecting the comparison with the lowest sum.

I'd use a functional approach so that you can refine your result by a query parameter (property key(s)). This approach will continue to work even if the two objects don't share the same property keys, and it will also allow you to easily refactor if the standard property keys change in your data:

```js
const defaultKeys = ['salt', 'sugar'];

function getSimilarityScore (a, b, keys = defaultKeys) {
  let score = 0;
  for (const key of keys) score += Math.abs((a[key] ?? 0) - (b[key] ?? 0));
  return score;
}

function closest (objList, obj, keys = defaultKeys) {
  let minScore = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  let result;

  for (const o of Object.values(objList)) {
    const score = getSimilarityScore(obj, o, keys);
    if (score >= minScore) continue;
    minScore = score;
    result = o;
  }

  return result;
}

const fruits = {
  apple: {
    salt: 5,
    sugar: 12,
  },
  banana: {
    salt: 3,
    sugar: 13,
  },
};

const cucumber = {
  salt: 3,
  sugar: 12,
};

const closestToCucumber = closest(fruits, cucumber);
const closestToCucumberBySalt = closest(fruits, cucumber, ['salt']);
const closestToCucumberBySugar = closest(fruits, cucumber, ['sugar']);

console.log(closestToCucumber === fruits.banana); // true
console.log(closestToCucumberBySalt === fruits.banana); // true
console.log(closestToCucumberBySugar === fruits.apple); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function for this purpose and compute the sum of absolute differences, finding the minimum such sum and returning the fruit corresponding this value. I returned its name, but if you want a different return format, let me know.

```js
let fruits = {
 apple:{
  sugar:12,
  salt:5
 },
banana:{
  sugar:13,
  salt:3
 },
}

let cucumber = {
 sugar:12,
 salt:3
}

function getClosestFruit(fruits, vegetable) {
    let output = undefined;
    let score = 0;
    for (let key in fruits) {
        let fruit = fruits[key];
        let currentScore = Math.abs(fruit.sugar - vegetable.sugar) + Math.abs(fruit.salt - vegetable.salt);
        if ((!output) || (score > currentScore)) {
            output = key;
            score = currentScore;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(getClosestFruit(fruits, cucumber));
```

Comment: Nice, and if I wanted to check only for sugar? not summing them up

Comment: Don't add the salt part to currentScore?

Comment: @kurome you can also pass a key or a set of keys to avoid and in the `for` cycle check whether the key is something to avoid. This approach is called blacklisted. Or you can do a whitelisting, that is, pass some key or key set that you want to process and ignore everything else. It would be a third variable of the function, so you need a refactor if you want to apply something of the like.